# JNI HellowWorld unsatisfiedlinkError Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, c++, gcc, java-native-interface, mingw

I've try the Hello world JNI from:

http://home.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/cs510ajp/

I did the Java class:

```
public class ACTICamWrapperJNI {
    public native void displayMessage();
  static 
  {
    System.loadLibrary("HelloWorldImp"); 

}

}
```

and call it in:

```
     public static void main(String args[]) {

            //</editor-fold>
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));

   ACTICamWrapperJNI test = new ACTICamWrapperJNI();
   }
```

the cpp file looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"   // this header file was generated by javah
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_displayMessage(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) 
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

I have switch to JDK x86 and compiled with X86:

```
C:\Development\testJNI>javac HelloWorld.java

C:\Development\testJNI>javac HelloWorld.java

C:\Development\testJNI>javah -jni HelloWorld
```

I used the gcc of MINGW32 I had in QT folder (hope that is ok)

```
C:\Development\testJNI>gcc -shared -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\include\win32" HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorldImp.dll
```

Note I had to add shared otherwise I got the error:

```
 undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

C:\Development\testJNI>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java.exe" Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: HelloWorld.displayMessage()V
        at HelloWorld.displayMessage(Native Method)
        at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Note that I've make sure that I'm running the java of x32 jdk and compiled with the x32 version too as I have the x64 on my system too.

Tried on NetBean IDE as well and got the issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\HelloWorldImp.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
    at au.com.ricor.ACTICamWrapperJNI.<clinit>(ACTICamWrapperJNI.java:15)
    at au.com.ricor.CameraPanel.main(CameraPanel.java:58)
```

As well the version of gcc I use is:

```
C:\Development\testJNI>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/qt/tools/mingw48_32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4
.8.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-4.8.0/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --buil
d=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw32 --with-sysroot=/t
emp/x32-480-posix-dwarf-r2/mingw32 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-mul
tilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-
threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=
release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --d
isable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-isl-version-check --disable-cloog
-version-check --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-boots
trap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --d
isable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic
--with-host-libstdcxx='-static -lstdc++' --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --wi
th-gmp=/temp/mingw-prereq/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/temp/mingw-prereq
/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/temp/mingw-prereq/i686-w64-mingw32-static -
-with-isl=/temp/mingw-prereq/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-cloog=/temp/mingw-pr
ereq/i686-w64-mingw32-static --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-pkgversion='rev2,
 Built by MinGW-builds project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mi
ngwbuilds/ CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/temp/x32-480-posix-dwarf-r2/libs/include -I/temp
/mingw-prereq/x32-zlib/include -I/temp/mingw-prereq/i686-w64-mingw32-static/incl
ude' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/temp/x32-480-posix-dwarf-r2/libs/include -I/temp/min
gw-prereq/x32-zlib/include -I/temp/mingw-prereq/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include'
 CPPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe -L/temp/x32-480-posix-dwarf-r2/libs/lib -L/temp/mingw-
prereq/x32-zlib/lib -L/temp/mingw-prereq/i686-w64-mingw32-static/lib -L/temp/x32
-480-posix-dwarf-r2/mingw32/opt/lib'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.0 (rev2, Built by MinGW-builds project)
```

Thanks

William

Answer (score 0):

Either rename the class from **au.com.ricor.ACTICamWrapperJNI** to **HelloWorld**, or the native function (in C++ file) from **Java_HelloWorld_displayMessage()** to **Java_au_com_ricor_ACTICamWrapperJNI_displayMessage()**

Answer (score 0):

I know this has an answer, but I determined that if you are compiling as Debug, it is not redistributable to another PC; you can try compiling for Release, and that should work.  I just used this to resolve [my own issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068381/why-is-this-jni-based-jboss-module-throwing-error-cant-find-dependent-librarie).